# Keras Transformer: Incompatible shapes [64,8,20,20] vs. [64,64,20,20]

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm working off an example ([link](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/neural_machine_translation_with_transformer/)) of using autoencoders to translate text from English to Spanish. I have the code setup exactly as the example but it's failing with the error:

> Incompatible shapes: [64,8,20,20] vs. [64,64,20,20]    [[{{node
> gradient_tape/transformer/transformer_encoder/multi_head_attention/softmax/add/BroadcastGradientArgs}}]]
> [Op:__inference_train_function_16963]

Here's my complete code:

```
with open('spa.txt', encoding="utf8") as f:
    lines = f.read().split("\n")[:-1]
text_pairs = []
for line in lines:
    eng, spa = line.split("\t")
    spa = "[start] " + spa + " [end]"
    text_pairs.append((eng, spa))
random.shuffle(text_pairs)
num_val_samples = int(0.15 * len(text_pairs))
num_train_samples = len(text_pairs) - 2 * num_val_samples
train_pairs = text_pairs[:num_train_samples]
val_pairs = text_pairs[num_train_samples : num_train_samples + num_val_samples]
test_pairs = text_pairs[num_train_samples + num_val_samples :]

strip_chars = string.punctuation + "¿"
strip_chars = strip_chars.replace("[", "")
strip_chars = strip_chars.replace("]", "")

vocab_size = 15000
sequence_length = 20
batch_size = 64


def custom_standardization(input_string):
    lowercase = tf.strings.lower(input_string)
    return tf.strings.regex_replace(lowercase, "[%s]" % re.escape(strip_chars), "")


eng_vectorization = TextVectorization(
    max_tokens=vocab_size, output_mode="int", output_sequence_length=sequence_length,
)
spa_vectorization = TextVectorization(
    max_tokens=vocab_size,
    output_mode="int",
    output_sequence_length=sequence_length + 1,
    standardize=custom_standardization,
)
train_eng_texts = [pair[0] for pair in train_pairs]
train_spa_texts = [pair[1] for pair in train_pairs]
eng_vectorization.adapt(train_eng_texts)
spa_vectorization.adapt(train_spa_texts)

def format_dataset(eng, spa):
    eng = eng_vectorization(eng)
    spa = spa_vectorization(spa)
    return ({"encoder_inputs": eng, "decoder_inputs": spa[:, :-1],}, spa[:, 1:])


def make_dataset(pairs):
    eng_texts, spa_texts = zip(*pairs)
    eng_texts = list(eng_texts)
    spa_texts = list(spa_texts)
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((eng_texts, spa_texts))
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.map(format_dataset)
    return dataset.shuffle(2048).prefetch(16).cache()


train_ds = make_dataset(train_pairs)
val_ds = make_dataset(val_pairs)

class TransformerEncoder(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim, dense_dim, num_heads, **kwargs):
        super(TransformerEncoder, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.embed_dim = embed_dim
        self.dense_dim = dense_dim
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        self.attention = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
            num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim
        )
        self.dense_proj = keras.Sequential(
            [layers.Dense(dense_dim, activation="relu"), layers.Dense(embed_dim),]
        )
        self.layernorm_1 = layers.LayerNormalization()
        self.layernorm_2 = layers.LayerNormalization()
        self.supports_masking = True

    def call(self, inputs, mask=None):
        if mask is not None:
            padding_mask = tf.cast(mask[:, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis, :], dtype="int32")
        attention_output = self.attention(
            query=inputs, value=inputs, key=inputs, attention_mask=padding_mask
        )
        proj_input = self.layernorm_1(inputs + attention_output)
        proj_output = self.dense_proj(proj_input)
        return self.layernorm_2(proj_input + proj_output)


class PositionalEmbedding(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, sequence_length, vocab_size, embed_dim, **kwargs):
        super(PositionalEmbedding, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.token_embeddings = layers.Embedding(
            input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=embed_dim
        )
        self.position_embeddings = layers.Embedding(
            input_dim=sequence_length, output_dim=embed_dim
        )
        self.sequence_length = sequence_length
        self.vocab_size = vocab_size
        self.embed_dim = embed_dim

    def call(self, inputs):
        length = tf.shape(inputs)[-1]
        positions = tf.range(start=0, limit=length, delta=1)
        embedded_tokens = self.token_embeddings(inputs)
        embedded_positions = self.position_embeddings(positions)
        return embedded_tokens + embedded_positions

    def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):
        return tf.math.not_equal(inputs, 0)


class TransformerDecoder(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim, latent_dim, num_heads, **kwargs):
        super(TransformerDecoder, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.embed_dim = embed_dim
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        self.attention_1 = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
            num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim
        )
        self.attention_2 = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
            num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim
        )
        self.dense_proj = keras.Sequential(
            [layers.Dense(latent_dim, activation="relu"), layers.Dense(embed_dim),]
        )
        self.layernorm_1 = layers.LayerNormalization()
        self.layernorm_2 = layers.LayerNormalization()
        self.layernorm_3 = layers.LayerNormalization()
        self.supports_masking = True

    def call(self, inputs, encoder_outputs, mask=None):
        causal_mask = self.get_causal_attention_mask(inputs)
        if mask is not None:
            padding_mask = tf.cast(mask[:, tf.newaxis, :], dtype="int32")
            padding_mask = tf.minimum(padding_mask, causal_mask)

        attention_output_1 = self.attention_1(
            query=inputs, value=inputs, key=inputs, attention_mask=causal_mask
        )
        out_1 = self.layernorm_1(inputs + attention_output_1)

        attention_output_2 = self.attention_2(
            query=out_1,
            value=encoder_outputs,
            key=encoder_outputs,
            attention_mask=padding_mask,
        )
        out_2 = self.layernorm_2(out_1 + attention_output_2)

        proj_output = self.dense_proj(out_2)
        return self.layernorm_3(out_2 + proj_output)

    def get_causal_attention_mask(self, inputs):
        input_shape = tf.shape(inputs)
        batch_size, sequence_length = input_shape[0], input_shape[1]
        i = tf.range(sequence_length)[:, tf.newaxis]
        j = tf.range(sequence_length)
        mask = tf.cast(i >= j, dtype="int32")
        mask = tf.reshape(mask, (1, input_shape[1], input_shape[1]))
        mult = tf.concat(
            [tf.expand_dims(batch_size, -1), tf.constant([1, 1], dtype=tf.int32)],
            axis=0,
        )
        return tf.tile(mask, mult)

embed_dim = 256
latent_dim = 2048
num_heads = 8

encoder_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None,), dtype="int64", name="encoder_inputs")
x = PositionalEmbedding(sequence_length, vocab_size, embed_dim)(encoder_inputs)
encoder_outputs = TransformerEncoder(embed_dim, latent_dim, num_heads)(x)
encoder = keras.Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_outputs)

decoder_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None,), dtype="int64", name="decoder_inputs")
encoded_seq_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None, embed_dim), name="decoder_state_inputs")
x = PositionalEmbedding(sequence_length, vocab_size, embed_dim)(decoder_inputs)
x = TransformerDecoder(embed_dim, latent_dim, num_heads)(x, encoded_seq_inputs)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
decoder_outputs = layers.Dense(vocab_size, activation="softmax")(x)
decoder = keras.Model([decoder_inputs, encoded_seq_inputs], decoder_outputs)

decoder_outputs = decoder([decoder_inputs, encoder_outputs])
transformer = keras.Model(
    [encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs, name="transformer"
)

epochs = 1  # This should be at least 30 for convergence

transformer.summary()
transformer.compile(
    "rmsprop", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"]
)
transformer.fit(train_ds, epochs=epochs, validation_data=val_ds)
```

Would really appreciate any help in getting past the error.

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

So I was able to get past that error by ensuring the *num_heads* is same as the *batch_size*. But it doesnt sound right to me. So my question to the group, do they always need to be the same? It's obviously different in the Keras example, so how is it working there?

Comment: Have you successfully run the example code without any change?

Comment: That's correct, the code is "as-is" from the link

Comment: @M.Innat I just realized some ambiguity in my response. I have not been able to successfully run the example code from the link. This is the as-is code with the same dataset and I am running into the error.

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem. I cannot run this code on server unless I set the batch size equal to num_heads, although it works on colab without setting them equal. Do you have any further updates on this issue?

Comment: Good question and a good update from the questioner.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem. An interesting thing I found is that I can run the code in colab, but I failed to run the same code when I just copied it to a local jupyter notebook.

Also I think it is not necessary to keep *num_heads* same as *batch_size*, since the size of each batch will be varied during training if the size of training data is not multiples of *batch_size*, while *num_heads* is a constant. It will cause anouther incompatible shapes error.

Comment: do you know why it fails? Is the Keras dev team aware of it?